# Javadoc multiple packages

Tags: java, documentation, package, javadoc

I am trying to generate java documentation for multiple packages so I have a single index.html, I can generate them fine for single packages by writing,

```
 javadoc packages/mypackage1/program/*.java
```

but I can't get it to work for multiple packages. I tried using javadoc @packages but I get

```
error - cannot read packages <access is denied>
```

Any ideas would be great!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`javadoc -d [DESTINATION_FOLDER] -sourcepath [SOURCE_FOLDER] -subpackages [PACKAGE1]:[PACKAGE2]`

For example, if your hierarchy is:

- /home/my_project/src/com/foo/Class1.java
- /home/my_project/src/fr/foo/Class2.java

Then your command line will look like:

`javadoc -d [DESTINATION_FOLDER] -sourcepath /home/my_project/src -subpackages com:fr`

Answer (score 1):

Let's give an example:

The following command line will process all the packages under com **and** LOR (lord of the rings) located into /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java **and** /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/

Please note:

- it is Linux and the paths and packages are separated by ':'.
   (on Windows, separated by ';').
- that I made usage of private and wanted all the classes and members to be documented.

---

```
rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~$ javadoc -d /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo_doc
-sourcepath /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java/
:/home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/
-subpackages com:LOR 
-private

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java$ ls -R 
.: com LOR
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: DemowApplication.java
./LOR: Race.java TolkienCharacter.java

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java$ ls -R 
.: com
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: AssertJTest.java DemowApplicationTests.java
```

Comment: Nice answer with example.  I'll just add that with Windows you need to add a ";" for the separator for multiple source paths